# Oracle: Finding locked row returns wrong row ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB 19c that is the basis for a customer application.

When the application accesses a table row it locks it and then the application launcehd from another computer cannot access this record anymore. I want to find out who and which computer locks which record.

In my research I found this how-to: http://www.orafaq.com/node/854
It lists quite well the steps to do and finally I ended up creating the following query for my purposes:

```
select LCK.*,OBJ.*,SESS.*, (CASE WHEN SESS.ROW_WAIT_OBJ# > -1 THEN dbms_rowid.rowid_create( 1, obj.Object_ID, SESS.ROW_WAIT_FILE#, SESS.ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#, SESS.ROW_WAIT_ROW# ) ELSE 'NA' END) as ROWID111
from v$locked_object LCK
left join dba_objects OBJ
on LCK.OBJECT_ID = OBJ.OBJECT_ID
left join v$session SESS
on LCK.SESSION_ID = SESS.SID;
```

My goal is to return the row of the table that is locked.

Unfortunately the dbms_rowid.rowid_create() method does not generate the correct row ID.
I did some reverse engineering and found out that...

- the Object ID to provide to rowid_create() must be the object_id from dba_objects
- SESS.ROW_WAIT_FILE# is pointing to the correct file
- SESS.ROW_WAIT_BLOCK is NOT the block ID of the table containing the locked record
- SESS.ROW_WAIT_ROW# is NOT the row number of the locked record

It seems that somehow the v$session table is not containing the information I need to retrieve the correct values for generating the rowID....

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following statements across different Oracle version and I never had any issue

**Get blocking sessions and associated processes**

```
set lines 300
COLUMN username FORMAT A30
COLUMN osuser FORMAT A10
COLUMN machine FORMAT A30
COLUMN logon_time FORMAT A20
COLUMN PROGRAM format a20
COLUMN MODULE format a20
COLUMN sid_serial_inst format a20

SELECT level,
       LPAD(' ', (level-1)*2, ' ') || NVL(s.username, '(oracle)') AS username,
       s.osuser,
       s.sid || ',' || s.serial# || ',@'|| inst_id as sid_serial_inst,
       s.blocking_session,
       s.lockwait,
       s.status,
       s.module,
       s.machine,
       s.program,
       TO_CHAR(s.logon_Time,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS logon_time
FROM   gv$session s
WHERE  level > 1
OR     EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   gv$session
               WHERE  blocking_session = s.sid and inst_id=s.inst_id)
CONNECT BY PRIOR  s.sid || '@inst'|| inst_id = s.blocking_session || '@inst'|| inst_id 
START WITH s.blocking_session IS NULL;
```

**To get the rows locked**

```
set lines 200
select s.sid,do.object_name,
row_wait_obj#, row_wait_file#, row_wait_block#, row_wait_row#,
dbms_rowid.rowid_create ( 1, ROW_WAIT_OBJ#, ROW_WAIT_FILE#, ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#, ROW_WAIT_ROW# )
from v$session s, dba_objects do
where sid in (SELECT sid FROM  GV$LOCK WHERE  request>0)
and s.ROW_WAIT_OBJ# = do.OBJECT_ID ;
```

**DEMO**

**Session 1**

```
SQL> create table test1 ( c1 number, c2 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1 values ( 1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test1 values ( 2,2) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.
```

**Session 2**

```
SQL> update test1 set c1=3 where c1=2 ;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

**Then again in Session 1**

```
SQL> update test1 set c1=4 where c1=2 ;
```

Here the session is locked, waiting for the other one to commit or rollback, so let's run the query to check the rows affected

```
SQL> r
  1  select s.sid,do.object_name,
  2  row_wait_obj#, row_wait_file#, row_wait_block#, row_wait_row#,
  3  dbms_rowid.rowid_create ( 1, ROW_WAIT_OBJ#, ROW_WAIT_FILE#, ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#, ROW_WAIT_ROW# )
  4  from v$session s, dba_objects do
  5  where sid in (SELECT sid FROM  GV$LOCK WHERE  request>0)
  6* and s.ROW_WAIT_OBJ# = do.OBJECT_ID

Session-ID OBJECT_NAME                    ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW# DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_C
---------- ------------------------------ ------------- -------------- --------------- ------------- ------------------
       601 TEST1                                1032538              1          123257             1 AAD8FaAABAAAeF5AAB
```